# BSON serializer/deserializer

Tags: java, php, bson

Is there a BSON serializer/deserializer library out there for PHP or Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check the MongoDB drivers for those languages, since MongoDB uses BSON. See what they use, or steal their implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is [BSON4Jackson](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson) extension for [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org), which adds support for BSON reading/writing.

Answer (score 1):

BSON encoder/decoder in Java is pretty trivial. The following snippet of code is from my app, so it's in Scala. I am sure you could build a Java implementation from it easily.

```
import org.bson.BSON
import com.mongodb.{DBObject, DBDecoder, DefaultDBDecoder}

def convert(dbo: DBObject): Array[Byte] =
  BSON.encode(dbo)

// NB! this is a stateful object and thus it's not thread-safe, so have
// to create one per decoding
def decoder: DBDecoder = DefaultDBDecoder.FACTORY.create

def convert(data: Array[Byte]): DBObject =
  // NOTE: we do not support Ref in input, that's why "null" for DBCollection
  decoder.decode(data, null)

def convert(is: InputStream): DBObject =
  // NOTE: we do not support Ref in input, that's why "null" for DBCollection
  decoder.decode(is, null)
```

The only significant note is that `DBEncoder` instance has an internal state it (re)uses during decoding, so it's not thread-safe. It should be ok if you decode objects one by one, but otherwise you'd better create an instance per decoding session.

Answer (score 1):

check this link
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mongo.php

bson_decode — Deserializes a BSON object into a PHP array

bson_encode — Serializes a PHP variable into a BSON string

Answer (score 0):

And here is a C++11 JSON encoder and decoder I've made using Rapidjson, because the native JSON encoder (`BSONObj::jsonString`) uses a non-standard encoding for longs: https://gist.github.com/ArtemGr/2c44cb451dc6a0cb46af

Also, unlike the native JSON encoder, this one doesn't have a problem decoding top-level arrays.